# Adding duplicates in a custom Set

Tags: java, collections

A step ahead in tweaking the API.

Basically, Set doesn't allow for duplicate entries.

But when I would be writing a customized Set how could it be achieved to allow adding duplicates?

Comment: A map of lists?

Comment: May I ask why you want a Set which allows duplicates?

Comment: You should look into Guava's `Multiset` ADT.

Comment: What you need is called a `bag` or `multiset`. Apache commons collections has a bag datastructure, and Guava has a multiset.

Comment: @Javaguy I would need an inverse. Just an ask on how to achieve just in case, If I might require to add duplicates in set to behave like other Collections.

Answer (score 3):

A set by its very mathematical [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) is:

> A well-defined collection of distinct objects

This is also reiterated in the [Java definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

So in your case, you would need to use a List in order to have duplicates.

Comment: Sure, but a better bet would be to quote the Java definition, rather than the mathematical definition.  (There's no reason for them to be identical...)

Comment: I believe it is counter-productive for a programming language to have a data structure which contradicts its mathematical equivalent. That being said, I added the Java definition to remove ambiguity. Thanks.

Comment: As a simple example - a "function" in most programming languages does not correspond to the mathematical definition.

Comment: Fair enough and I agree, but I was comparing data structures here.

Answer (score 2):

`Set`, in Java, by definition is a data structure which cannot have duplicates. So, if you want a data structure which allows duplicates, you might want to use `java.util.List` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, but serious answer: do **not** do that.

You are basically asking: how should I draw a triangle that has 4 corners? Or how do I prepare a vegetarian meal using chicken wings?!

The Java [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface is **meant** to not allow duplicates. That is one of the essential cornerstones of that concept. And there is no "but".

You are suggesting to **violate** the contract that Set gives.

In other words: inheritance and polymorphism is more than just writing down `A extends B`. There are rules that one has to understand when creating subclasses; or new implementations of interfaces. For example the [Liskov Substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

Assume you got:

```
Set<Integer> someSet = new HashSet<Integer>;
someSet.add(1); someSet.add(1);
System.out.println(someSet);
```

Should show **one** entry in the set afterwards. If you now go for

```
Set<Integer> someSet = new YourSpecialDuplicatesAllowingSet<Integer>;
someSet.add(1); someSet.add(1);
```

all of a sudden ... someSet might contain **two** entries.

Long story short: your idea would achieve only two things: confusing other people; and thereby creating a lot of potential for ugly bugs. *Hard* bugs; as those things were "contracts" are violated in such ways are often hard to find and debug!

Given your comment: doing this would be rather easy:

```
public class FakedSet<T> implements Set<T> {
  private final List<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();
  @Override
  public void add(T elem) { elements.add(T); }
```

and so on; you would @Override all methods that the Set interfaces has; and try to implement them somehow. Don't ask how to do that in a reasonable manner; because well; that is not possible!

Comment: Just curious to know how can this be achieved. Overriding equals and hashcode is suffice here or something more to be done.. Just a thought nothing to implement as such.

Comment: For the sake of it ... I put another paragraph into my answer to give an idea how you could do that. Maybe the exercise of doing that could show you even more how bad of an idea that is ...so, well: go try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have correctly stated, there doesn't exist a set that contains duplicates, neither in Java nor in mathematics.

But you might want to have a map that counts how many duplicates you have:

```
Map<Whatever, Long> multiset = new HashMap<>();
```

To add an element, use the [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
multiset.merge(someElement, 1, (oldValue, value) -> oldValue + 1);
```

And to remove an element, you might want to use the [`computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
multiset.computeIfPresent(someElement, (key, value) -> (value == 1 ? null : value - 1));
```